# Firebase: App reiniciando sozinho

Tags: android, firebase, app, realtime-database

Estou desenvolvendo um app android, e estou usando o Realtime Database do Firebase para armazenar os dados. Lá eu tenho um nó de usuários, com todos os usuários que eu cadastrei através do meu App. Quando eu faço alguma alteração nos dados do usuário que está logado (por exemplo adicionar um item na sua lista de livro), é como se meu app reiniciasse rapidamente chamando a função de login de novo e voltando para a tela principal, algo muito estranho. O mais estranho é que isso também acontece se eu fizer essa alteração manualmente no próprio Firebase, o app também volta para a tela principal e mostra o toast que tem na função de Login: "Login efetuado com sucesso!", como se estivesse chamando a função de login novamente. Isso está me parecendo coisa do próprio Firebase, alguém sabe o que é isso que está acontecendo e o porque? Existe alguma forma de mudar isso? Quero conseguir fazer uma alteração e continuar na Activity que eu estou sem que meu app reinicie.

Essa é a minha LoginActivity (Quando altero alguma informação no usuário que está logado, é como se o app reiniciasse rapidamente chamando essa função validadeLogin(), ai volta para a MainAcativity e mostra o Toast "Login efetuado com sucesso!" assim como nessa função):

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText userInput;
private EditText passwordInput;
private Button btLogin;
private TextView btSignUp;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private User user;
private LinearLayout layoutLogin;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private DatabaseReference firebase;
private User currentUser;
private Preferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    preferences = new Preferences(LoginActivity.this);
    user = new User();

    if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Entrando como " + preferences.getName());
        progressDialog.show();
        user.setEmail(preferences.getEmail());
        user.setPassword(preferences.getPassword());
        validateLogin();
    }

    userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInputLogin);
    passwordInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordInputLogin);
    layoutLogin = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutLogin);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Entrando...");

    btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogin);
    btLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (!Objects.equals(userInput.getText().toString(), "") && !Objects.equals(passwordInput.getText().toString(), "")){

                user.setEmail(userInput.getText().toString());
                user.setPassword(passwordInput.getText().toString());

                progressDialog.show();

                validateLogin();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Preencha os campos de e-mail e senha", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    btSignUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btSignUp);
    btSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpPersonalDataActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void validateLogin(){
    auth = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseAuth();
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                FirebaseUser userFirebase = task.getResult().getUser();
                firebase = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("user").child(userFirebase.getUid());

                firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                        String myBooksIds = "";
                        if(currentUser.getMyBooks() != null) {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(myBooksIds);
                            for (int i = 0; i < currentUser.getMyBooks().size(); i++) {
                                stringBuilder.append(currentUser.getMyBooks().get(i) + " ");
                            }
                            myBooksIds = stringBuilder.toString();
                        }

                        String myListIds = "";
                        if(currentUser.getMyList() != null) {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilderMyList = new StringBuilder(myListIds);
                            for (int i = 0; i < currentUser.getMyList().size(); i++) {
                                stringBuilderMyList.append(currentUser.getMyList().get(i) + " ");
                            }
                            myListIds = stringBuilderMyList.toString();
                        }

                        preferences.saveUserPreferences(currentUser.getId(), currentUser.getName(), currentUser.getEmail(), currentUser.getPassword(), myBooksIds, myListIds);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        progressDialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login efetuado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erro desconhecido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.w("ERRO", "loadUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                progressDialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "E-mail ou senha inválidos!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Esse é um Fragment da minha MainActivity, onde eu registro um livro no Firebase, estou registrando um livro no nó "book' do firebase, e adiciono também o id desse livro na propriedade "myBooks" do usuário que está logado. Ao ao adicionar este id na lista de livros do usuário, o app reinicia misteriosamente a MainActivity e mostra o Toast "Login efetuado com sucesso!", como se tivesse chamado a função de login.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);

    userPreferences = new Preferences(getContext());

    firebase = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("user").child(userPreferences.getID()).child("myBooks");

    if (firebase != null){
        firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                myBooks.clear();

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String myBooksCurrent = data.getValue().toString();

                    myBooks.add(myBooksCurrent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    bookNameInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bookNameInput);
    bookAuthorInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthorInput);
    bookPublishingCompanyInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bookPublishingCompanyInput);
    bookSynopsisInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.bookPublishingCompanyInput);

    genresSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.bookGenreSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(), R.array.genres_spinner, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    genresSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    btAddBook = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btAddBook);
    btAddBook.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (Objects.equals(bookNameInput.getText().toString(), "")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Informe o nome do livro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (Objects.equals(bookAuthorInput.getText().toString(), "")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Informe o autor do livro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (Objects.equals(genresSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Selecione o gênero")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Informe o gênero do livro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (Objects.equals(bookPublishingCompanyInput.getText().toString(), "")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Informe a editora do livro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if (Objects.equals(bookSynopsisInput.getText().toString(), "")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Informe a sinopse do livro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {

                book = new Book();
                book.setName(bookNameInput.getText().toString());
                book.setAuthor(bookAuthorInput.getText().toString());
                book.setPublishingCompany(bookPublishingCompanyInput.getText().toString());
                book.setGenre(genresSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                book.setSynopsis(bookSynopsisInput.getText().toString());
                book.setAvaliable(true);
                book.setOwnerID(userPreferences.getID());

                String idBook = Base64Custom.base64Encoding(book.getName() + userPreferences.getID());
                book.setId(idBook);

                registerBook(book);
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private boolean registerBook(Book book) {
    try{

        firebase = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("book");
        firebase.child(book.getId()).setValue(book);
        myBooks.add(book.getId());

        firebase = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("user");
        firebase.child(userPreferences.getID()).child("myBooks").setValue(myBooks);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Livro cadastrado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Mas como já mencionei, eu adicionar esse id na lista de livros do usuário manualmente no site do firebase, acontece a mesma coisa, a MainActivity é reiniciada e aparece o toast "Login efetuado com sucesso!".

Comment: poste o codigo usado. sem codigo fica dificil.

Comment: Sem o codigo realmente fica difícil entender o problema, mas pela sua descrição, e não afirmando com certeza, você tem algum problema nos seus ValueListeners do firebase. Poste o codigo que a gente olha rapidinho.

Comment: É porque eu realmente não sei em que parte do código pode haver um problema, nem mesmo o arquivo. Como eu disse, até mesmo uma edição manual no próprio site do firebase faz com que isso ocorra. Mas vou botar alguns trechos que acho que podem estar envolvidos.

Comment: Pronto! Adicionei o código da minha LoginActivity e de um Fragment onde estou alterando uma propriedade do usuário que está logado como exemplo.

Comment: Experimente utilizar `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` ao invés de `addValueEventListener` no método `validateLogin()`

Answer (score 0):

Isso está acontecendo porque o trecho abaixo está dentro de `onDataChange`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
progressDialog.cancel();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login efetuado com sucesso!
```

A função onDataChange é chamada toda vez que os dados no nó são alterados, ja que você usou `addValueEventListener`.

O Rosário Pereira Fernandes sugeriu que você usasse `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, isso resolveria o problema mas não é recomendável carregar dados enquanto você está completando o login.

O ideal nesse caso é completar o login e mudar para a `Activity` que vai mostrar os dados, só então solicitar os dados ao Firebase.

Aqui está um link para a documentação do Firebase sobre recuperar dados, que pode ajudar esse caso e outros problemas que você tiver:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data?hl=pt-br